# Erlang how to start an external script in linux

Tags: erlang

I want to run an external script and get the PID of the process (once it starts) from my erlang program. Later, I will want to send TERM signal to that PID from erlang code. How do I do it?

I tried this

```
P = os:cmd("myscript &"),
io:format("Pid = ~s ~n",[P]).
```

It starts the script in background as expected, but I dont get the PID.

**Update**

I made the below script (loop.pl) for testing:

```
while(1){
    sleep 1;
}
```

Then tried to spawn the script using open_port. The script runs OK. But, erlang:port_info/2 troughs exception:

```
2> Port = open_port({spawn, "perl loop.pl"}, []).
#Port<0.504>
3> {os_pid, OsPid} = erlang:port_info(Port, os_pid).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:port_info/2
        called as erlang:port_info(#Port<0.504>,os_pid)
```

I checked the script is running:

```
$ ps -ef | grep loop.pl
root    10357 10130  0 17:35 ?        00:00:00 perl loop.pl
```

Comment: Try running `erlang:port_info(Port)`, with just the `Port` argument alone, and make sure one of the tuples it returns has `os_pid` as its first element. If there's no such tuple, your version of Erlang is older and doesn't support `os_pid`.

Comment: You might find erlexec useful: https://saleyn.github.io/erlexec/

Comment: Watch out for daemons, they like to fork and merge into the background, defeating your OS pid acquisition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [open a port](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#open_port-2) using `spawn` or `spawn_executable`, and then use [`erlang:port_info/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#port_info-2) to get its OS process ID:

```
1> Port = open_port({spawn, "myscript"}, PortOptions).
#Port<0.530>
2> {os_pid, OsPid} = erlang:port_info(Port, os_pid).
{os_pid,91270}
3> os:cmd("kill " ++ integer_to_list(OsPid)).
[]
```

Set `PortOptions` as appropriate for your use case.

As the last line above shows, you can use `os:cmd/1` to kill the process if you wish.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I tried your code but getting error from erlang:port_info/2.
6> Pp.
#Port<0.2188>
7> {os_pid, P} = erlang:port_info(Pp, os_pid).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:port_info/2
        called as erlang:port_info(#Port<0.2188>,os_pid)

Comment: If you get `undefined` from `port_info`, that most likely means the OS process spawned in creating the port has already exited. You might try running `flush().` in the shell to see if the process sent any output that might indicate why it died. I have no idea what your `myscript` does, where you keep it, or exactly how you're calling it, so it's hard to provide more advice.

Comment: Steve's answer is spot on, but in this case the badarg response indicates erlang:port_info does not recognise os_pid. The os_pid is a recent addition, it's in R17, but probably not too many releases before, if any. To get the pid without this feature is trickier, my archives are littered with ports I wrote which, when they start, send their pid to Erlang before they do anything else. You could probably create a wrapper that does this if you can't add the feature to myscript.

Comment: I updated my erlang and now it working .. thanks a lot. Just one more question how do I print this Pid? If I do like, io:format("Pid = ~s ~n",[Pid]) I get error.

Comment: Use `~p` rather than `~s`, since the latter is only for printing strings.